# ¿Cómo puedo cambiar de versión de python con conda?

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

He tenido problemas para cambiar de la versión de python 2.7 a la versión 3.6 utilizando conda. Intente esto:

```
conda install python=3.6.1
```

Según la documentación de conda debería funcionar, pero me tira este error:

```
UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be in conflict:
- enum34 -> python 3.3*
- python 3.6.1*
```

Desinstalé el enum34 pero me tira otro error no se que tengo que hacer.

Este es el error al desinstalarlo:

```
RemoveError: Error: this 'remove' command cannot be executed because it would require removong 'conda' dependencies
```

Gracias a todos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He probado a crear un entorno virtual en Python 2.7 y la actualización funciona sin problemas:

```
$ conda create -n _test27 python=2.7
Fetching package metadata .........
Solving package specifications: .

Package plan for installation in environment /home/juanlu/.miniconda36/envs/_test27:

The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

    openssl:    1.0.2l-0     
    pip:        9.0.1-py27_1 
    python:     2.7.13-0     
    readline:   6.2-2        
    setuptools: 27.2.0-py27_0
    sqlite:     3.13.0-0     
    tk:         8.5.18-0     
    wheel:      0.29.0-py27_0
    zlib:       1.2.8-3      

Proceed ([y]/n)? 

python-2.7.13- 100% |###########################################################################| Time: 0:00:02   6.00 MB/s
setuptools-27. 100% |###########################################################################| Time: 0:00:00   6.79 MB/s
wheel-0.29.0-p 100% |###########################################################################| Time: 0:00:00   8.10 MB/s
pip-9.0.1-py27 100% |###########################################################################| Time: 0:00:00   6.54 MB/s
#
# To activate this environment, use:
# > source activate _test27
#
# To deactivate an active environment, use:
# > source deactivate
#

$ source activate _test27
(_test27) $ conda install "python=3.6.1"
Fetching package metadata .........
Solving package specifications: .

Package plan for installation in environment /home/juanlu/.miniconda36/envs/_test27:

The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

    xz:         5.2.2-1      

The following packages will be UPDATED:

    pip:        9.0.1-py27_1  --> 9.0.1-py36_1 
    python:     2.7.13-0      --> 3.6.1-2      
    setuptools: 27.2.0-py27_0 --> 27.2.0-py36_0
    wheel:      0.29.0-py27_0 --> 0.29.0-py36_0

Proceed ([y]/n)?
```

Te sugiero que actualices `conda` primero, no vaya a ser que tengas una versión antigua que no permita hacer esta operación.

```
$ conda update conda
Fetching package metadata .........
Solving package specifications: .

Package plan for installation in environment /home/juanlu/.miniconda36:

The following packages will be UPDATED:

    conda: 4.3.22-py36_0 --> 4.3.24-py36_0

Proceed ([y]/n)?
```

Si aun así no funciona, copia la salida de `conda info -a` y añádela a tu pregunta. Puedes editar la pregunta original.

Comment: ¡Gracias!. Ya lo pude actualizar. Un saludo

Comment: De nada @Jflorian5655, no olvides marcar la respuesta como buena usando la marca verde en "V" :)